# Assign IP address using saltstack

Tags: saltstack

How can I use `Execution Modules` and also `State Modules` to assign IP addresses to linux minions?

It's simple to do this on minions using windows, I'm not sure how to do this for linux minions.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of unknowns here, such as the distribution you are using or the details of the task at hand (do you want to do this manually through Salt, have it dynamically selected from a list, etc), but I have a reccomendation.

Might I recommend using the state `file.managed` to modify the network configuration file on a linux instance?  The configuration itself depends on the distribution type, but you can find out [how config files and configs differs from distro to distro here.](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-configure-a-static-ip-address-tutorial/)

Use the [file.managed state or other file manipulation states](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/all/salt.states.file.html) to modify proper the network configuration files to meet your needs!

Additionally, there are in fact states which allow you to modify the networking directly through Saltstack - `salt.states.network`. Search it out in the docs -- I don't have enough rep to post more than 2 links! :)